# How to properly separate columns

Tags: apache-spark, delimiter, databricks

I'm having trouble with Spark SQL. I tried to import a CSV file into spark DB. My columns are separated by semicolons. I have tried to separate the columns by using `sep` to do so, but to my dismay, the columns are not separated properly.

Is this how Spark SQL works or is there a difference the conventional Spark SQL and the one in DataBricks. I am new to SparkSQL, a whole new environment from the original SQL language, sorry pardon me for my knowledge for SparkSQL.

```sql
USE CarSalesP1935727;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "/FileStore/tables/Products.csv", header "true", inferSchema
"true", sep ";");

SELECT * FROM Products LIMIT 10
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the problem, working well -

> Please note that the env is not `databricks`

```scala
  val path = getClass.getResource("/csv/test2.txt").getPath
    println(path)

    /**
      * file data
      * -----------
      * id;sequence;sequence
      * 1;657985;657985
      * 2;689654;685485
      */
    spark.sql(
      s"""
        |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products
        |USING CSV
        |OPTIONS (path "$path", header "true", inferSchema
        |"true", sep ";")
      """.stripMargin)

    spark.sql("select * from Products").show(false)
    /**
      * +---+---------+---------+
      * |id |sequence1|sequence2|
      * +---+---------+---------+
      * |1  |657985   |657985   |
      * |2  |689654   |685485   |
      * +---+---------+---------+
      */
```